# Comparing dates and create values for new columns in Python

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe in Python named "final"

| purchase_date | Expiration_date | is_trial_period | current_date. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-10-12 | 2013-12-12 | FALSE | 2021-10-05 |
| 2013-10-12 | 2013-12-12 | FALSE | 2021-10-05 |

The datatypes of final dataframe are

```
purchase_date:datetime64[ns]
,Expiration_date:datetime64[ns]
,is_trial_period:object
,current_date:datetime64[ns],
dtype: object
```

I want to create a new column called XYZ. if is_trail_period is FALSE & Expiration_date >= current_date, the value of XYZ column should be Active Subscription else Expired Subscription

How can I do that in Python ??

I tried doing

```
final['XYZ'] = np.where(final['is_trial_period']== 'FALSE'& (final['Expiration_date'] >= final['current_date']), 'Active Subscription','Expired Subscription')
```

But then I am getting an error "TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [bool] array and scalar of type [bool]"

I want my final output to be like

| purchase_date | Expiration_date | is_trial_period | current_date. | XYZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2013-10-12 | 2013-12-12 | FALSE | 2021-10-05 | Expired Subscription |
| 2013-10-12 | 2013-12-12 | FALSE | 2021-10-05 | Expired Subscription |

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply`:

```
final['XYZ'] = final.apply(lambda x: 'Active Subscription' if x['is_trial_period'] == 'FALSE' and (x['Expiration_date'] >= x['current_date']) else 'Expired Subscription', axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a comparison between a single bool and an array, which I believe is because you have not enclosed the first condition in parentheses. Try this:

```py
final['XYZ'] = np.where((final['is_trial_period'] == 'FALSE') & (final['Expiration_date'] >= final['current_date']), 'Active Subscription','Expired Subscription')
```